# GCD proof - one way solved

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let a,b be positive integers.  Prove there exist positive integers $c$, $d$ such that $cd = a$ and $\gcd(c,d) = b$ if and only if $b^2\mid a$.

Proof exists $cd=a$ and $\gcd(c,d) = b \Rightarrow b^2\mid a$:

Let c = bm, d = bn.  Then $cd = b^2mn = a$ and so $b^2\mid a$.

Not quite sure how to prove $b^2\mid a$ -> exists $cd=a$ and $\gcd(c,d) = b$. I thought maybe proof by contraposition.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof has a gap. You should take $c=bm$ and $d=bn$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ because then only you can ensure $\gcd(c,d)=b$.

**For the other implication** 
Since $a=b^2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a=b(bk)$. Now consider $c=b$ and $d=bk$.